# Would embedding my CSS/JS/Sprite in my single-page web-app make it load faster?

Tags: html, performance, http

I have single page web-app that currently consists of four files:

- `index.html`
- `main.js`
- `style.css`
- `sprites.png`

This means that every user who loads the site has to request index.html, parse it for the other three files, and then make three more http requests (serially, I believe) to fetch the remaining files.

It seems to me that it might be (a tiny bit) faster to embed the javascript, css and sprite image (base64 encoded) directly in the `index.html` file.

The main reasons I can think *not* to do this, along with my reasons why I don't think they apply in this case, are as follows:

- Would prevent any of these additional files from being cached separately. This is not an issue for me because they will never be loaded from another page (since there is only one html page)
- If the files were on different CDN servers, they could be downloaded in parallel. (Currently this project is not large enough to merit multiple servers)

I should disclose that this site is a small pet project that is no-where near large enough to merit this kind of meticulous performance tuning, but I like using pet projects as an avenue to explore problems (and their solutions) that I may face in my day job.

Comment: But what if I visit your web page twice, or twenty times? All the content will get loaded every time, instead of cached.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Good point. I hadn't considered that the html file would not be cached. I suppose I could set the http header in such a way that it would be, (right?) but then I would have a hard time pushing updates. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also note that Base64 encoded data is roughly 33% larger than the original binary form.

Comment: @Pekka웃 If you could make your comment an answer, I will mark it as accepted. I think you caught the main reason not to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't usually done because you increase the size of the entire HTML page. You'll save a couple requests on the first visit, but you'll force the client to reload *everything* every time they fetch the HTML file.

It would improve performance for users who visit your site once, and only once. For any kind of long-term strategy, it's unsuitable.

Answer (score 1):

When your page is reloaded js,  images, and CSS are cached on the client and doesnt need to reload. Also, base64 requires your clients to activate JavaScript to see your page. Lastly, it may very well take a weak client longer to decode your base64 than downloading the files.
So in short, dont overthink some things.

Comment: I agree  embedding  all this stuff in a web page is a bad idea, but `base64 requires your clients to activate JavaScript to see your page` is incorrect. Base64 encoded images in CSS work fine without JS